# Difference between laplace and capillary pressure

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, capillary-action

Is there a difference between laplace and capillary pressure in the context of immiscible fluids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're manifestation of the same phenomenon, i.e. surface tension, but we need information about the material of the capillarity to describe capillarity.

**Pressure jump across a surface.** It is described by Young-Laplace equation,

$\Delta P = 2 \gamma H = \gamma \left( \dfrac{1}{R_1} + \dfrac{1}{R_2} \right)$,

that relates the pressure jump with the surface tension $\gamma$, and the mean curvature $H = 2\left( \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2}\right)$.

**Pressure in a capillary.** If you want to know the pressure in a capillary in steady conditions, you also need to know the material of the capillary and the **angle of contact** $\theta$, that can be seen as a physical property of the interface between the three phases, as an example, air, fluid and the solid of the wall.

Once you know $\gamma$ and $\theta$, you need to:

- write the **equilibrium** of the volume of water in the capillary
- use **Stevino** law to find the pressure distribution in the fluid.

If the height of fluid in the capillary is $h$ over the free
surface of "non capillary" fluid, the vertical equilibrium of this
volume of fluid in a capillary with circular section reads

$\gamma 2\pi R \cos \theta - \pi R^2 h \rho g = 0$$\qquad \rightarrow \qquad h = \dfrac{2 \gamma \cos \theta}{\rho g R}$.

Stevino law in the capillary gives you that

$P_{atm} - P_h = \rho g h$$\qquad \rightarrow  \qquad$
$P_h = P_{atm} - 2 \dfrac{\gamma \cos \theta}{R}$.

**Interpretation of the formulas.** You can see that the height in the capillary depends on $g$,

- on the angle of contact $\theta$: if $\theta < \pi/2$ then $h >0$, like water, air and glass; if $\theta > \pi/2$ then $h < 0$, like mercury, air and glass;

If $\theta < \pi/2$,

- dimension of the capillary $R$: the smaller the radius $R$, the higher the height $h$;
- surface tension $\gamma$: the higher the surface tension, the higher the height $h$
- density $\rho$: the denser the fluid, the lower the height;